Limits of Compact Operators: a simple question about the diagonal trick.
Theorem. Let $H$ and $K$ be
Hilbert spaces, and assume that $T_n\colon H \to K$ is compact for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
If $T \in B(H,K)$ is such that $\lVert T − T_n\rVert \to 0$, then $T$ is compact.
Proof. Suppose that $\{x_n\}_n$ is a bounded sequence in $H$. Since $T_1$ is compact, there exists a subsequence $\{x_{1, n}\}_n$ of $\{x_n\}_n$ such that $\{T_1 (x_{1,n})\}_n$ converges. Then, since $T_2$ is compact there exists a subsequence $\{x_{2,n}\}_n$ of $\{x_{1,n}\}$ such that $\{T_2(x_{2,n})\}_n$ converges.

We observe that $\{T_1(x_{2,n})\}$ also converges. $\tag1\label{4959570_1}$

Continue to construct subsequences in this way.
By construction. for every $m$ the vector $x_{m,m}$ belongs to the subsequence $\{x_{1,n}\}_n$. Likewise, if $m \ge 2$, then $x_{m,m}$ is an element of $\{x_{2,n}\}_n$. In general, if $k\in \mathbb{N}$, then $\{x_{m,m}\}_{m\ge k}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_{k,n}\}_n$. Therefore $\{T_k (x_{m,m})\}_{m \ge k}$ converges.

It's all very clear, I just don't understand why it's important to make the observation \eqref{4959570_1}. Are we using this observation somewhere?

Question 2. If we say that the sequence $\{T_k (x_{m,m})\}_{m\ge k}$ converges, can we conclude that the sequence $\{T_k (x_{m,m})\}_{m\in\mathbb{N}}$ also converges?
EDIT
I still don't understand this diagonal trick. It's clear that for each $k\in\mathbb{N}$ exists a subsequence $\{x_{k,n}\}_n$ of $\{x_n\}$ such that $$\{T_j x_{k,n}\}_n\quad\text{converges for}\quad j=1,\dots, k \tag 2$$
It is also clear to me that $\{x_{m,m}\}_{m\ge k}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_{k,n}\}$ and therefore $\{T_k x_{m,m}\}$ converges.
From this how can I conclude that for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ fixed, result that  $\{T_k x_{m,m}\}_m$ converges? Where am I missing out? Where is (2) used?

It seems to me that it's just a more explicit statement for the special case $k=1$ of the last paragraph, probably to motivate it/make it more understandable.

The idea of the diagonal trick here is similar to the one used in the proof of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem you may have seen in earlier analysis classes.
What one wants is a subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}_{k\geq 1}$ along which the collection $\{T_n(x_{n_k})\}_{k\geq 1}$ converges for any fixed $n$ as $k\to \infty$. The diagonal of the collection $\{x_{n,m}\}_{n,m\geq 1}$ as constructed is precisely such a sequence. To see this, fix some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ arbitrarily. Notice that along the diagonal $\{x_{m,m}\}$, if $m\geq k$ then this sequence is a subsequence of $\{x_{k,n}\}_{n\geq 1}$. Now, since $\{T_k(x_{k,n})\}_{n\geq 1}$ converges to some point $a_k$ by the construction outlined in (1), any subsequence also converges to $a_k$ (because it is also eventually in an $\varepsilon$-ball about $a_k$). Therefore, since $\{T_k(x_{m,m})\}_{m\geq 1}$ is eventually such a subsequence (for $m\geq k$), it converges to $a_k$. So the answer to your question 2 is yes because changing finitely many terms does not affect the limit behaviour.
So, (1) is important since it (along with the ad infinitum extension) gives that for any fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$, there exists some sequence $\{a_n\}\subset K$ such that, $$\Vert T_n(x_{m,m})-a_n\Vert \xrightarrow{m\to \infty} 0$$ These $a_n$'s are the limit points, $T_n(x_{m,m})\xrightarrow{m \to \infty}a_n$ which exist by the iterative construction outlined in (1).
We can also prove that this sequence of limit points, $\{a_n\}$, is itself Cauchy since $$\begin{align*}\Vert a_n - a_k\Vert &\leq \Vert a_n -T_n(x_{m,m})\Vert + \Vert T_n(x_{m,m})-T_k(x_{m,m})\Vert +\Vert T_k(x_{m,m})-a_k\Vert \\
&\xrightarrow{\min\{n,k\}\to\infty}0\end{align*}$$
And therefore, as $K$ is complete, $a_n$ is convergent to some $a\in K$.
With this result in hand, we can now outline why the diagonal trick is useful. Consider, $$\begin{align*}\Vert T(x_{m,m})-a\Vert &\leq \Vert T(x_{m,m})-T_n(x_{m,m})\Vert +\Vert  T_n(x_{m,m})-a_n\Vert+\Vert a_n-a\Vert\\
&\leq \Vert T-T_n\Vert \underbrace{\Vert x_{m,m}\Vert}_{<M<\infty}+\Vert  T_n(x_{m,m})-a_n\Vert+\Vert a_n-a\Vert \\
&\xrightarrow{m\to \infty}\Vert T-T_n\Vert M+\Vert a_n-a\Vert \\
&\xrightarrow{n\to \infty} 0\end{align*}$$ Hence, we have found a convergent subsequence, so $T$ is compact.
There is one subtlety that I have glossed over. The reason we can send $m\to \infty$ before sending $n\to \infty$ is because $m$ is free for us to choose. In particular, we can make $m$ a function of $n$, so that for any $n$ as we let $n\to\infty$, $\Vert  T_n(x_{m,m})-a_n\Vert$ is small.

I hope that I correctly understand Your questions and the following will shed some light on why the diagonal trick is used.
Let $x_m$ be a bounded sequence, $\|x_m\|< B$. $T_p\rightarrow T$ in the norm topology. The aim is to show the existence of a subsequence $y_k=x_{m_k}$ such that $Ty_k$ is Cauchy.
A faulty proof would proceed like this. Let $T_p$ be chosen by the condition $\|T-T_p\|<\epsilon$. Choose $y_k$ so that $T_py_k$ is Cauchy in the index $k$. Then, for large enough $k$ and $l\geq 1$ arbitrary,
$$\|Ty_{k+l}-Ty_{k}\|\leq \|(T-T_p)y_{k+l}\|+\|(T-T_p)y_{k}\|+\|T_p(y_{k+l}-y_{k})\|<2\epsilon B + \epsilon,$$
which would prove the statement.
But this is not a proof. Indeed, we proved only the following statement: for every $\epsilon > 0$, we can find a subsequence $y_k$ of $x_m$ (possibly $\epsilon$ dependent) for which $Ty_k$ is essentially within a ball of radius $C\epsilon$.
This is not enough to prove the statement: it can happen that the same sequence fails to be essentially within nested balls of ever decreasing radius.
So we have to somehow construct a subsequence $y_k$ on which $Ty_k$ is Cauchy before picking up an $\epsilon$ to test convergence.
Now, the sequence $Ty_k$ is Cauchy in a Hilbert space if and only if $\lim_kTy_k$ exists. Formally, we can write
$$\lim_kTy_k=\lim_k(\lim_pT_p)y_k$$
and if the order of the limits can be reversed, then
$$\lim_kTy_k=\lim_k(\lim_pT_p)y_k=\lim_p(\lim_kT_py_k).$$
If $y_k$ is such that $\lim_kT_py_k=z_p$ exists for all $p$, then the proof of the existence of $\lim_kTy_k$ is equivalent to the proof that $z_p$ is Cauchy. This suggest that we should look for a subsequence $y_k$ such that for all $p$, $\lim_k T_py_k$ exists.
So we break the proof into two Parts.
Part 1. Let $x_n$ be a bounded, non-zero sequence, $\|x_n\|\leq B$. Let $T_p$ be a norm convergent sequence of compact operators, $T_p\rightarrow T$. If there exists a subsequence $x_{n_k}$ of $x_n$ such that for all $p$, $T_px_{n_k}$ is Cauchy in the index $k$, then $Tx_{n_k}$ is Cauchy.
Part 2. Such a subsequence always exists.
Proof of Part 1. Let $y_k=x_{n_k}$ again. For any $p,k,l\geq 1$,
$$\|Ty_{k+l}-Ty_{k}\|<\|(T-T_p)(y_{k+l}-y_k)\|+\|T_py_{k+l}-T_py_k\|.$$
For any $\epsilon>0$, one can find $N(p,\epsilon)$ and $M(\epsilon)$ such that
$$\|T-T_p\|<\epsilon/(4B)\ \ if \ \ p>M(\epsilon),$$
$$\|T_py_{k+l}-T_py_{k}\|<\epsilon/2\ \ if \ \ k>N(p,\epsilon).$$
So choosing $p$ according to $p>M(\epsilon)$ enables us to choose $k>N(p,\epsilon)$ and conclude
$$\|Ty_{k+l}-Ty_{k}\|<\epsilon$$
independently of $l$.
Proof of Part 2. The construct the subsequence $y_k$, we consider the original sequence $y^{(0)}_k=x_k$. First we construct the subsequence $y^{(1)}_k$ as a sequence on which $T_1$ converges. Then proceed with the iterative steps consisting of choosing a subsequence of $y^{(r)}_{k}$ on which $T_{r+1}$ converges resulting in $y^{(r+1)}_k$. Now comes the diagonal trick. We set $y_k=y^{(k)}_k$. We prove that all limits $T_py_k$ exists. Fix the value of $p$. Note that if $k>p$, than all members $y_k$ are members of the sequence $y^{(p)}_l$. Therefore, they form a subsequence of the latter, so the convergence of $T_py^{(p)}_l$ implies the convergence of $T_py_k$: for some strictly increasing function $l(k)$, $$\lim_{k}T_py_k=\lim_kT_py^{(p)}_{l(k)}.$$
Regarding your Question 2, $y_{k}$, $k>p$ is a subsequence of $y_k$, $k\leq 1$, so Yes, $T_py_k$ $k\leq 1$ converges if $T_py_k$ $k> p$ converges.

From $2$, we could show that for $k\in \mathbb{N}$, $\{T_{k}x_{m,m}\}_{m}$ converges since $\{x_{m,m}\}_{m\geq k}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_{k,n}\}_{n}$.
So for $\epsilon >0$, there exist  $N_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $||T_{n}-T||<\epsilon /3K$, for all $n \geq N_{0}$, where $K$ is the bound of $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$. There exist $M_{0} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $||T_{N_{0}}x_{n,n} -T_{N_{0}}x_{m,m}|| <\epsilon /3$ for all $n,m > M_{0}$.
Thus, $||Tx_{n,n} -Tx_{m,m}|| \leq ||Tx_{n,n} -T_{N_{0}}x_{n,n}||+||T_{N_{0}}x_{n,n} -T_{N_{0}}x_{m,m}||+||T_{N_{0}}x_{m,m} -Tx_{m,m}|| <\epsilon$. Hence $\{Tx_{m,m}\}_{m}$ is cauchy hence converges.
